# Highcharts - Exporting to PDF Issues with Font (Arial)

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts, graphics

Holi, Im having this trouble with one Bar Chart using Highchart library, I'm trying to export it and it works perfectly fine on  PNG, JPEG.  But when i'm trying to export as PDF it has some font troubles even with the "default" **Arial.**.  Originally i was using Barlow as my principal font, but it does the same problem. Im using offline exporting.

[Exporting as PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqeUQ.png)

[Exporting as JPEG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Y8A.jpg)

```
                    "lang": {
                        "contextButtonTitle": "Opciones",
                        "viewFullscreen": "Ver en pantalla completa",
                        "exitFullScreen": "Salir de pantalla completa",
                        "printChart": "Imprimir",
                        "downloadJPEG": "Descargar imagen JPEG",
                        "downloadPDF": "Descargar PDF",
                        "downloadPNG": "Descargar imagen PNG",
                        "downloadSVG": "Descargar imagen SVG",
                        "thousandsSep": ","
                    },
                    "chart": {
                        "backgroundColor": "#3D4553"
                    },
                    "title": {
                        "visible": true,
                        "template": "date_range",
                        "templateConfig": {
                            "originalDateFormat": "Y-MM-DD",
                            "originalTimeFormat": "hh:mm:ss",
                            "dateFormat": "DD-MM-Y",
                            "timeFormat": "hh:mm a",
                            "dateProperty": "fecha_creacion",
                            "timeProperty": "hora_creacion"
                        },
                        "style": {
                            "color": "#FFFFFF",
                            "fontSize": "14px",
                            "fontFamily": "Arial",
                            "fontWeight": "bold"
                        },
                        "verticalAlign": "top",
                        "align": "center",
                        "floating": false
                    },
                    "subtitle": {
                        "style": {
                            "color": "#FFFFFF",
                            "fontFamily": "Arial"
                        }
                    },
                    "tooltip": {
                        "backgroundColor": "#1d222b",
                        "borderColor": "#1d222b",
                        "borderWidth": 1,
                        "borderRadius": 0,
                        "style": {
                            "color": "#FFFFFF"
                        }
                    },
                    "xAxis": [{
                        "type": "category",
                        "labels": {
                            "style": {
                                "color": "white",
                                "fontFamily": "Arial"

                            }
                        },
                        "title": {
                            "style": {
                                "color": "white",
                                "fontFamily": "Arial"
                            }
                        }

                    }],
                    "yAxis": {
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Reportes",
                            "style": {
                                "color": "white"
                            }
                        },
                        "labels": {
                            "style": {
                                "color": "white"
                            },
                            "format": "{value:,.0f}"
                        },
                        "gridLineColor": "#43b5e5",
                        "gridLineWidth": 0
                    },
                    "legend": {
                        "enabled": false
                    },
                    "exporting": {
                        "enabled": true
                    },
                    "noData": {
                        "style": {
                            "color": "white"
                        }
                    }
```

My best regards, hoping that someone can help me.  Thank you

Comment: With your configuration I can't reproduce your problem, could you check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7c8p3xws/1/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at some point i got it working, it seems to be a exporting issue with size and length of the text's name's  that i was trying to show... thankyou for your comments and help!